# Как сделать три полоски в виде кнопки в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, c++, qt

[image]Я относительно новенький в Qt и хочу сделать кнопку в виде трёх полосок или трёх кружков рядом стоящих (после нажатия которых обычно всплывают другие окна) в Qt Designer, но не знаю как. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь обычную кнопку и укажи text равный "☰" или "≡" или "⋮".